# Display data from json file in ionic project

Tags: javascript, json, html, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm having a problem regarding getting the output of the ionic project where the data fetched by a json file. Even though i double checked for syntax errors i couldn't find the error.  I tried to use ionic commands but the result is same

```js
   

Angular modules

angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      

      
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('ListController',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('js/cars.json).success(function(data){
        $scope.cars=data;
    });
}]);
```

```css
//Json file

{
    data: [{
        manufacturer: 'Porsche',
        model: '911',
        price: 135000,
        wiki: 'Dr.-Ing. h.c. F. Porsche AG, usually shortened to Porsche AG, is a German automobile manufacturer specializing in high-performance sports cars, SUVs and sedans',
        img: '2004_Porsche_911_Carrera_type_997.jpg'
    },{
        manufacturer: 'Nissan',
        model: 'GT-R',
        price: 80000,
        wiki:'Nissan Motor Company Ltd, usually shortened to Nissan, is a Japanese multinational automobile manufacturer headquartered in Nishi-ku, Yokohama, Japan',
        img: '250px-Nissan_GT-R.jpg'
    },{
        manufacturer: 'BMW',
        model: 'M3',
        price: 60500,
        wiki:'Bayerische Motoren Werke AG, usually known under its abbreviation BMW, is a German luxury vehicles, motorcycle, and engine manufacturing company founded in 1916',
        img: '250px-BMW_M3_E92.jpg'
    },{
        manufacturer: 'Audi',
        model: 'S5',
        price: 53000,
        wiki:'Audi AG is a German automobile manufacturer that designs, engineers, produces, markets and distributes luxury vehicles. Audi oversees worldwide operations from its headquarters in Ingolstadt, Bavaria, Germany',
        img: '250px-Audi_S5.jpg'
    },{
        manufacturer: 'Ford',
        model: 'TT',
        price: 40000,
        wiki:'Audi AG is a German automobile manufacturer that designs, engineers, produces, markets and distributes luxury vehicles. Audi oversees worldwide operations from its headquarters in Ingolstadt, Bavaria, Germany',
        img: '250px-2007_Audi_TT_Coupe.jpg'
    }]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

                 
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

   
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

   
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
        <h1 class="title">Vehicle Search</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
        <div clas="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset bar-light">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search"> 
            </label>
        </div>
        
      <ion-content ng-controller="ListController" class="has-subheader">
        <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat='item in cars' class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
            <img src="img/{{item.manufacturer}}.jpg" alt="{{item.model}} Photo">
            <h2><b>{{item.manufaturer}}</b></h2>
            <h3>{{item.model}}</h3>
            <h4>{{item.price}}</h4>
            <p>{{item.wiki}}</p>
        </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some formatting issues with your code.  First of all, you need to use double-quotes in your JSON file like so:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "manufacturer": "Porsche",
        "model": "911",
        "price": "135000",
        "wiki": "Dr.-Ing. h.c. F. Porsche AG, usually shortened to Porsche AG, is a German automobile manufacturer specializing in high-performance sports cars, SUVs and sedans",
        "img": "2004_Porsche_911_Carrera_type_997.jpg"
    },{
        "model": "GT-R",
        "manufacturer": "Nissan",
        "price": "80000",
        "wiki":"Nissan Motor Company Ltd, usually shortened to Nissan, is a Japanese multinational automobile manufacturer headquartered in Nishi-ku, Yokohama, Japan",
        "img": "250px-Nissan_GT-R.jpg"
    },{
        "manufacturer": "BMW",
        "model": "M3",
        "price": "60500",
        "wiki":"Bayerische Motoren Werke AG, usually known under its abbreviation BMW, is a German luxury vehicles, motorcycle, and engine manufacturing company founded in 1916",
        "img": "250px-BMW_M3_E92.jpg"
    },{
        "manufacturer": "Audi",
        "model": "S5",
        "price": "53000",
        "wiki":"Audi AG is a German automobile manufacturer that designs, engineers, produces, markets and distributes luxury vehicles. Audi oversees worldwide operations from its headquarters in Ingolstadt, Bavaria, Germany",
        "img": "250px-Audi_S5.jpg"
    },{
        "manufacturer": "Ford",
        "model": "TT",
        "price": "40000",
        "wiki":"Audi AG is a German automobile manufacturer that designs, engineers, produces, markets and distributes luxury vehicles. Audi oversees worldwide operations from its headquarters in Ingolstadt, Bavaria, Germany",
        "img": "250px-2007_Audi_TT_Coupe.jpg"
    }]
}
```

You are also not accessing the correct object.  The following line:

```
$scope.cars=data;
```

Should be changed to:

```
$scope.cars=data.data;
```

`data` contains the `$http.get` result which is the entire JSON object so you would actually want to iterate through `data.data`.

You also have a missing single quote here:

```
$http.get('js/cars.json)
```

Change that to:

```
$http.get('js/cars.json')
```

These changes should fix your problem.

Comment: I edited as you mentioned but still the previous results

Comment: I have updated my answer.  The new one should work for you.

Comment: It worked Thanks a lot ankur... u saved my day.. i was not much aware on json my mistake..

Comment: Glad I could help.  :)